# How to instal Hadoop tools on AWS cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and big data. I have setup a 4 node working Hadoop cluster in AWS. I wanted to what are the different tools I can install on that and how to install them. My plan is to stream twitter data to HDFS and then looking for specific patterns . What are the tools available for this task.

Thanks in advance.
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily see what technologies you can have available to your cluster when you request it, and AWS will take care of the installation.

Just go to EMR, create a cluster, then click on advanced options, and you will see something like this:

[image: aws emr]

If you're asking which technology is best suited to your particular use case, then maybe you should post a separate question when you've figured out exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Great...Thanks Raj